# How to conditionally load a script in Astro

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I have an Astro page that loads a local script as described in the docs:
https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/#import-local-scripts

This works but I'd like to load the script only in development mode, so I wrapped it an expression:

```html
---
const isDev = import.meta.env.DEV
---
{ isDev && <script src="../scripts/local.js"></script> }
```

This no longer works. Astro does not bundle the script and renders the HTML unchanged so I'm getting a 404 for the resource in dev mode.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a recommended way to conditionally load scripts?

Comment: Will the solution posted in this issue work for you: https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/3180

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Thank you!